# Save list of open tabs in Google Chrome when not responding?

Tags: google-chrome, crash

I left Google Chrome open on my XP host last night with a bunch of open tabs, and this morning, the applications stops responding.

I'm afraid killing and restarting Chrome won't recover the open tabs.

I tried making a copy of "C:\Documents and Settings(me)\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Current Tabs", but even though I'm logged in with Admin rights, I get "Access denied on file Current Tabs".

Is there a way to get the list of tabs currently open in the browser?

Thank you.

---

Edit: I went ahead, killed Chrome... and as I feared, it didn't recover the open tabs. By default, Google doesn't seem to handle this, so we have to change its configuration: Basics > On Start Up: "Reopen the pages that were open last".

If the above doesn't work, maybe there's an extension that keeps tracks of open URL's and will positively recover them after a crash?

A more rudimentary solution is to 1) kill Chrome, and 2) grep for "http" the following file: "C:\Documents and Settings(me)\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Current Session".

Comment: *"I'm afraid killing and restarting Chrome won't recover the open tabs."*  — this procedure has worked for me every single time. You can bring them up with `ctrl`-`shift`-`t` again when you restart Chrome. Are they that important? You could also search the History for the latest entries, in the unlikely event it doesn't restore them.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but CTRL-SHIFT-T didn't work, and Chrome just restarted without recoving the open tabs. They were important because I obviously didn't keep track of their URL's. As for using History, it's pretty useless since it's not possible to just retrieve URL's that were open when Chrome stopped responding.

Comment: That's weird — I remember when using earlier nightly builds that Chrome would crash every second day, and I was able to restore the tabs every time, since it saved their state immediately when they were opened.

Comment: Maybe it's because you changed its default config to "On Start Up: "Reopen the pages that were open last." I don't understand why Google doesn't enable this by default.

Comment: No, this isn't activated (see [my preferences](http://i.imgur.com/bTRnV.png)). The reason is that `ctrl-shift-t` should always work. Try it, open a few tabs, quit Chrome, open it again, and try the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work when it was not responding... which is when this feature is most needed :-/

Comment: After chrome crash, I always get a new button on the toolbar that looks a bit like the refresh button.  Clicking it restores my tabs.  Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Settings and there "On startup", "open the tabs that were open last time".

Works for me, ie. recovers the tabs also in case of a program crash.

Comment: Thanks. By default, it wasn't enabled, and I lost all the open tabs after killing Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

***1. Setting up Google Chrome***

- In Chrome <**'Settings'**> - <*'On Startup'*> you must set "*Open the New Tab page*" or (obviously) "*Continue where I left off*" (but then chrome will reopen all closed tabs in every new session - witch can cause some problems).
- You must **never select "*Open a specific page or set of pages.*"** - if you want, you can enable "**show Home page**" *checkbox*, under <*'Appearances'*> so you'll be able to quickly open *home page* at startup. I don't know the reason, but that's the price of always having "reopen last session" possibility.

***2. Reopening***

- After Crash you can use <'Reopen'> button (as always)
- After closing Google Chrome, **before opening any new (i.e. home) page**, press *ctrl+shift+T* or right click on *title bar* and then click on "Reopen closed tab"